# PowerShell drive change causes prompt

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with PowerShell on Windows 10.
When ever I change the drive by drive letter or Set-Location I get a ">>" prompt randomly.

This never happened on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the below code:

```
(Get-Command Prompt).Definition
```

This should return

```
"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
```

If it doesn't, overwrite this function with your own defintition:

```
Function Prompt {
    "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
}
```

Comment: This did not prevent the >> from popping up.  Here is what I get wen running  (Get-Command Prompt).Definition. 
"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
# .Link
# http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml

Comment: If you look at the code you'll also spot that you'd get `>>` when `$nestedPromptLevel -eq 1`.  Could you check the value of that variable / see if any of the causes for this variable to have been incremented exist (see "To summarize" section on the end of this blog post: http://dpotter.net/technical/2008/10/nestedpromptlevel/)